# What Names To Use and where, In Cookie jQuery Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, names

I'm just now learning about how to make jQuery scripts with cookies. I understand half of it and have working examples to go by, but I'm still very confused about a few things and need some clear answers so I can understand it better. So here are my questions.

1. For the cookie name, do I create a new name for that, or do I use an existing name from the script I am adding it to?
2. Do I create new Vars or use existing Vars?
3. I know about names, ids, and classes, but examples on the internet do not clarify details and they have me confused. Exactly what names am I adding and from where, to where?
4. If I am creating a cookie for one checkbox, do I need to create one cookie for the checkbox, or two cookies, one for each state of the checkbox?

EDIT: Added script I'm trying to add cookies to

```
<script language="javascript">

$(function() {
  var checkbox = $("#trigger");
  var hidden = $('.adult');
  var NSFW = " NSFW ";
  var SFW = " SFW ";
      hidden.hide();
  document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = SFW;
  checkbox.change(function() {
    if (checkbox.is(':checked')) {
      hidden.show();
      document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = NSFW;
    } else {
      hidden.hide();
      document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = SFW;
    }
  });
});

</script>

<body>

This Page Is Currently<input type="checkbox" id="trigger"><span id="content"></span>

</body>
```

Here is what I have so far for the cookie version. I haven't figured it out yet.

```
<script language="javascript">

$(function() {
  var checkbox = $("#trigger");
  var hidden = $('.adult');
  var NSFW = " NSFW ";
  var SFW = " SFW ";
  var NSFWcookie = document.cookie;
  alert( $.NSFWcookie("checkbox") );
    if (checkbox.is(':not(:checked)')) {
      hidden.hide();
  document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = SFW;
  checkbox.change(function() {
    if (checkbox.is(':checked')) {
      document.cookie = "checkbox=NSFWcookie";
      $.NSFWcookie("checkbox", "NSFWcookie", { expires: 360 });
      hidden.show();
      document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = NSFW;
    } else {
      $.NSFWcookie("checkbox", null, {path: '/'});
      hidden.hide();
      document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = SFW;
    }
  });
});

</script>

<body>

This Page Is Currently<input type="checkbox" id="trigger"><span id="content"></span>

</body>
```

I'm not sure If I'm making a cookie for checkbox or for trigger. Do I need to make new Vars or do I use existing Vars? This should be simple, but the main problem I'm having is that examples on the internet do not show script before and after adding the cookie script to them.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: 1. depends. 2. depends. 3. depends.  4. depends .... they all depend on what you are trying to achieve. With no code in the question it's hard to guess what you need

Comment: What are the cookies for? If you want to store some state info in the browser between sessions I'd use `localStorage` rather than cookies, much less trouble. For your question 4 I would think one cookie would do it.

Comment: I added a checkbox to a web page, and I just want to have the checkbox stay as it is when browser is refreshed. I haven't looked into LocalStorage yet.